# Merging Legends for both geom Line and Point

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I was very new to R Script. If you are able to help my problem that would be really great... Here is my problem...

I am able to create custom visual using R Script and make hover over work in that visual by using this below link [Link](http://radacad.com/interactive-map-using-r-and-power-bi-create-custom-visual-part-1) I think It is displaying legend for both line and point as well. This is how it’s showing me in the graph [Both Legends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKQkE.png)

[image]

But I would like to show up something like this…. Which represents both the line and point in the same legend name [Same legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i55wg.png).

[image]

Please find the R Script below, Please go through that and can you tell me where I was going wrong….

```
      source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')
```

## Library Declarations

```
      library(htmlwidgets);library(XML);library(ggplot2);library(plotly);

      Values$Storiesgrouping <- as.character(Values$Storiesgrouping)
      Cols <- as.character(Values$Color)
      names(Cols) <- as.character(Values$Builder_CommunityName)
      Sizs <- as.numeric(Values$Size)
      names(Sizs) <- as.character(Values$Builder_CommunityName)
```

## Actual code

```
g <- ggplot(Values, aes(x=BaseSquareFeet, y=BasePriceM, 
                        group=Builder_CommunityName, color=Builder_CommunityName))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Storiesgrouping), show.legend=FALSE,size=3)+ 
  scale_colour_manual(values = Cols)+
  scale_size_manual(values = Sizs)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("1"=19, "2"=15, "3+"=17)) 
plot(g)
```

## Create and save widget

```
p = ggplotly(g); internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50240153/786542

Comment: `Builder_CommunityName` and `Storiesgrouping` have different levels. This is why the legends can't be combined. It is hard for anyone to help you further, when you don't have a reproducible example.

Comment: @Axeman, Can i turn off the legend for geom_point? Then that should make up some sense to the user. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: `+ scale_shape_manual(guide = "none")`

Comment: Had the same problem and applied an ugly fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615148/1114975

Comment: @axeman Solution worked for me when I had the same problem. The color aesthetic for the points and lines color, and the shape aesthetic for the poits will plot together in ggplotly() if they have the same levels (or are set to the same variable and it is a factor with levels)